# How to set the Reply-To header using BizTalk SMTP adapter?

Tags: smtp, biztalk, biztalk-2016

MS BizTalk Server 2016

I try to send an email message using a Dynamic Port.

I initialize SMTP properties in the code like that:

```
EmailMessage(SMTP.Subject) = "ReplyTo test subject";
EmailMessage(SMTP.SMTPHost) = ..
EmailMessage(SMTP.From) = ..
EmailMessage(SMTP.SMTPAuthenticate) = 0;   
EmailMessage(SMTP.EmailBodyTextCharset) = "UTF-8"; 
EmailMessage(SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments) = 0;
EmailMessage(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.ContentType) = "text/html";
```

Looking through the list of available properties of an SMTP adapter [How to Configure an SMTP Send Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-configure-an-smtp-send-port)

I can't find how to set a Reply-To parameter. Can you help with this?

Comment: Hi Elena.  It doesn't look like they expose that as one of the properties you can set.  Why can't you set the From address to the address you want replies to?

Comment: Dijkgraaf, thanks for the idea. But is it ok to set several addreses as SMTP.From? Like that: "email1@mail.com;email2@mail.com;"? The initial requirements were to set a couple of receipients instead of a default sender.

Comment: Hi Elana. The alternative would be the put the additional addresses in the CC, but then if they hit reply instead of reply all it will only go to one.  So if you really need the reply to go to multiple recipients, set up a mail distribution list and use the address of that as the From address.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely there is not option to set the reply to address in the BizTalk SMTP adapter
even though they do havea  ReplyBy field that does mention it.

[SMTP Adapter Property Schema and Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/smtp-adapter-property-schema-and-properties)

> Name : ReplyBy 
> Type :  xs:dateTime
> Description :  Specify a dateTime value for the **Reply-To** header in the outgoing e-mail message.

See this thread [Reply-To in SMTP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc27f055-21b3-482c-84fc-3ae94b740f75/replyto-in-smtp?forum=biztalkr2adapters) that basically outlines these options.

1. Create a C# helper class that you call to send the email that you call from BizTalk
2. Create your own custom SMTP adapter that has that functionality
3. Use a 3rd party such as the email adapter from [/n software](https://www.nsoftware.com/adapters/biztalk/compare/email/)

The other option as per my comments, is to set the From address to where you want the replies to go, and if you want that to go to multiple people, make that an email distribution list email address.